# Asp.net core WebAPI route with optional parameter only not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, webapi

I'm trying to create a GET-Route which takes 4 optional Parameter. There are no required Parameter.

My Route looking like that

```
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [HttpGet("SearchWhatever", Name = "GetWhatever")]
    public IEnumerable<TmpObject> SearchWhatever(long? eid= null, long? pid = null, string name= null,  string firstname= null)
    {
        //do Smth
    }
```

Basically the "eid" and the "pid" are working as intended, they're completely optional. However the strings are not working as "optional".

If I'm calling the API like "../SearchWhatever?eid=6610232513694" I'll receive the following error:

```
{
errors: {
name: [
"The name field is required."
],
firstname: [
"The firstname field is required."
]
},
type: "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
title: "One or more validation errors occurred.",
status: 400,
traceId: "00-e4eb5dc9bb266e44abda734d6a411e44-5f5a40de7fc10540-00"
}
```

How do I achieve my goal? Is it even possible? I thought giving a string a default value like null makes the parameter optional already.

Thanks in advance

Comment: First of all, you don't have 'ean' query argument.

Comment: Fixed it, was just a typo (its correct in my code).

Comment: Try using "" as default value for your string arguments. ("... string name="",  string firstname= ""... ")

Comment: Tried this already but will produce the same error.

Comment: which version of asp.net core? 3.1?

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath Yes, its 3.1

Comment: can you try `string? name = null`. I know string takes null, but in 3.1 there is a feature called nullable reference type, if that's not causing issue, just in case

Comment: Its not possible for me to set string nullable -> "Only non-nullable value type could be underlying of 'System.Nullable'"

Comment: it's working properly for me (3.1 API controller action method). Can you check your Startup.cs file Configure method where UseEndPoint settings if router is set to make those parameter required.

Comment: It returns error because of your [Required] model validation. Remove `RequiredAttribute` in  model and it will perform as you think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a demo worked,firstly
add this to your controller:

```
#nullable enable
```

action(use `string? name,string? firstname`,because you use `nullable enable`,so the string type can be null):

```
[HttpGet]
        [Route("SearchWhatever")]
        public IEnumerable<String> SearchWhatever(long? eid, long? pid,string? name,string? firstname)
        {
            return new List<String> { "success" };
            //do Smth
        }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, this helped by just changing to `string?` in .NET 6, with an optional parameter:
`public IActionResult Get(String? applicationName = "Default")`
I believe this is related to this setting in my .csproj:
`<Nullable>enable</Nullable>`